# how to post 360 panoroma to facebook using php SDK?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, 360-panorama

How to post the 360degree image to Facebook using PHP Facebook SDK v5?
I tried using this parameter  'allow_spherical_photo'=> true, But it is not working.
Posting image as simple flat image.
here is my code

```
$message = '';
    $title = '';
    $link = 'http://google.com/';
    $description = 'My Image Posting';
   $url = 'My Public image url';
   $caption = 'My Image';

    $attachment = array(
      'message' => $message,
       'name' => $title,
       'allow_spherical_photo'=> true,
       'source' => $url,
       'description' => $description,
        'photo'=>$url,
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($attachment);
      try{
         echo "try";
        //Post to Facebook
     $fb->post('/me/feed', $attachment, $accessToken);

        //Display post submission status
        echo 'The post was submitted successfully to Facebook timeline.';
    }catch(FacebookResponseException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(FacebookSDKException $e){
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

can anyone help me out? I searched a lot.

Comment: mu must see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703553/posting-equirectangular-360-panoramas-on-facebook-using-javascript-graph-api

Comment: I referred that link. but it did not worked for me